# On the convergence in expectation of a recursive stochastic sequence.

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, statistics, optimization, convergence-divergence

Let $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_t$ be IID Gaussian random variables with zero mean and variance $e^{\sigma^2}$.

Take the recursive sequence given by
$$ \sigma_{t+1}^2 = \sigma_t^2 - \alpha \left( 1-  e^{-2\sigma_t^2} \left( \frac{1}{t}\sum_{i=0}^t X_i^2 \right)   \right)     $$

where $\alpha > 0$.

Are there values of $\alpha$ for which the sequence $\{ \sigma_t^2 \}$ will converge in expectation as $t \rightarrow \infty$  to $\sigma^2$?

PS: for those wondering how the recursive sequence is constructed it is a modified gradient ascent on the gaussian log-likelihood where we replace $X_i^2$ with $\frac{1}{t}\sum_{i=0}^t X_i^2 $. For those familiar with the gradient descent literature $\alpha$ can be thought of as a learning rate.